# UITableView - reloadRows method creating weired scrolling bug

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using `UITableView` in one of my app. inside tableview's row I have horizontal scrolling `UICollectionView`. Whenever user double tap on the collection view's cell it sends event back to the viewcontroller to update the datasource. After updation of datasource I am reloading that particular row using : `tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)` But I am getting weird scrolling bug.

I wanted to reload the tableview's row and it's content i.e collectionview's content  without any animation or scrolling issue.

I tried following solution to avoid this but no luck :(

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
}
```

I even tried to remember content offset of the tableview and collectionview but that flicker is still there. Please guide me if you have come across such problem

Comment: show us the "weird" scroll bug

Comment: It's scrolling from top and coming back to the prev position or previosly visible row.

Comment: If you want to update that row, don't reload it - You know that the cell is probably visible, since the user just interacted with it.  Retrieve the cell with `cellForRow(at:)` and update it.  If you get `nil` when you try and retrieve the cell, just move on since that cell isn't on screen and will be updated next time it appears

Comment: Don't you think there will be dequeing issue for such implementation?

Comment: No, the cell is either onscreen, in which case you can update it directly or it isn't on screen, in which case you don't have to do anything - Note, that I am talking about calling the `UIITableView` function [`cellForRow(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow), not the datasource method that you have implemented.

Comment: If there is any jerk in scroll, it will be most likely based on the estimatedHeight property. Adjust the estimatedHeight to be close to the average height of the cells and afaik this should fix it.

Comment: @CerlinBoss I haven't set estimated height row property to the tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a UI layout issue. When you reload a cell/section, it re-calculates its content size, hence your tableView content size specially if you have a dynamically sized cell. I would suggest 2 solutions

Solution I (Hacky):

- save the current view before-reload-state content offset of the table view and then scroll to it after the reload process with no animation

Solution II (Better):

- Update you data sources and their bonded cells directly without reloading your UITableView (consider maybe updating your UICollectionView instead - unless it's dynamically heisted you will need animate your UITableViewCell height).

Comment: Glad it did! :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. This alone fixed the problem:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Before placing the images into the cell, if possible, create thumbnails of the images, that rolls.

Answer (score -2):

try tableView.reloadData() or you have to rearrange the indexPath in ascending order then reload particular indexPaths.

Comment: I don't think reloading entire tableview is better idea

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger Even if you call `tableView.reloadData()` entire table wont be reloaded. Only the visible cells will be reloaded because other cells don't even exist.  TableView doesn't event create them

Comment: @CerlinBoss tableView.reloadData() will trigger the data source, which will be iterated for all the cells data but affected to the only visible cells.

Comment: @KumarKL i dont think so. Even if it does, there is no significance in front end since it reloads only the visible cells..

Comment: @CerlinBoss as per documentation : `Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of the reload. The table view’s delegate or data source calls this method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, `

Comment: @KumarKL can you show where in documentation it explains `will trigger the data source, which will be iterated for all the cells data` part?. I dont think there is anything called `data iteration`. The iteration happens based on the no of rows and no of sections mentioned and estimatedHeight of each cell.